# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - check a value in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to check of my panda column has a specific value using the code below:

```
if not df['my_col'].str.contains('my_value'):
```

But I got the following errors:

```
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/process/data_stats.py", line 225, in <module>
    if not df['my_col'].str.contains('my_value'):
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/process/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any idea what I did wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are checking if `my_col` contains `"my_value"` at any point in the column. In that case, use `.any`: `if not df['my_col'].str.contains('my_value').any():`.

Or, you could use: `if 'my_value' not in df['my_col'].values`, which might be faster than the `str` accessor

## Example: method 1 with `str`

```
>>> df
     my_col my_col2
0  my_value       x
1         x       x
2         x       x
3  my_value       x

if not df['my_col'].str.contains('my_value').any():
    print('not contained')
else:
    print('contained')
```

Returns: `contained`

But:

```
if not df['my_col2'].str.contains('my_value').any():
    print('not contained')
else:
    print('contained')
```

Returns `not contained`

## Example: method 2 with `not in`

Or for the other way:

```
if 'my_value' not in df['my_col'].values:
    print('not contained')
else:
    print('contained')
```